# Using functions within environments

Tags: r

I am currently trying to import a piece of code using the source() function. I created an environment to ensure that local variables/values are not overwritten/ deleted on importing function defined in another "R" script. I was expecting the variable/ value in the imported "R" script to use lexical scoping and return a result from the GLobal environment/ parent enviornment. This was not the case. Could someone explain the error? Also, is there another method to tackle this issue.

```
detach("new_tmp")
attach(new.env(), name="new_tmp")
my_newenv <- as.environment("new_tmp")
source("C:/Users/tmp/tmp.R", local=my_newenv)
search()

xxx <- "this should not be overwritten"
y <- 10

my_newenv$printing_func(10) # the result should be 20!
print(my_newenv$xxx) 

# <<< R script imported using source() function  >>>
# >>>
# >>>
xxx <- "this overwrote"
printing_func <- function(xx){
  xx + y
  print("it works")
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: There are two instances of `xxx`.  One is in the global environment and one is in `my_newenv`.  Neither overwrites the other.  `xxx` and `my_newenv$xxx` will access them respectively. Also `my_newenv$printing_func(10)` results in an error that it can't find `y`.

Comment: Hello G.Grothendieck, I am aware there is a an error that the function cannot find y. How would you suggest I resolve this issue?

Comment: Just don't attach anything.  Personally, I never use attach/detach.   `e <- new.env(); source("tmp.R", local = e); e$printing_func(20); xxx; e$xxx`  You could also look at the klmr modules package on github (not on CRAN) or write a package.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't attach anything. Personally, I never use attach/detach. e <- new.env(); source("tmp.R", local = e); e$printing_func(20); xxx; e$xxx You could also look at the klmr modules package on github (not on CRAN) or write a package. – G. Grothendieck

```
e <- new.env()
source("C:/Users/tmp/tmp.R", local=e)
search()

xxx <- "this should not be overwritten"
y <- 10

e$printing_func(10) # the result should be 20!
print(my_newenv$xxx) 

# <<< R script imported using source() function  >>>
# >>>
# >>>
xxx <- "this overwrote"
printing_func <- function(xx){
  xx + y
  print("it works")
}
```